# c# - How to check if current logged in user has access to page in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm writing a webpart for Sharepoint 2013. I have the url list of .aspx files under `Pages` . These are pages like aboutus.aspx, departments.aspx e.t.c. I need to check permissions of these pages for current logged in user and anonymous user. I get the files in a loop and I also have the CurrentUser but have no idea how I compare privileges.

```
//web.CurrentUser //Current user
foreach(...) {
    SPFile tmpfile = web.GetFile(tmpfilestring); //Page
    //need to compare privileges here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple API

> SPFile.CanOpenFile method (Boolean, String)
>
> Indicates whether the current user has permission to view the content
>   of the file, specifying a level of access and an output variable to
>   receive an ETag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee549635(v=office.15).aspx